# Custom Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have Gridview and I want to retrieve some Information from data base(SQL). and according to them, show typical information. for example: I read "Meal" field from DB, but I want to show lunch in my gridview. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TemplateField` that change the values as you wish, for example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Infos">
    <ItemTemplate ><%#GetTypicalInfo(Container.DataItem)%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind:

```
protected string GetTypicalInfo(object oItem)
{
    string cInfo = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "cDataField").ToString();

    switch (cInfo)
    {
        case "Meal":
            return "lunch";

        default:
            return cInfo;
    }   
}
```